# Is it possible to have a div be sticky to the bottom of the screen until you scroll down and hit the end of content?

Tags: html, css

Like image #2 here:

https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/1*gUfDwoSlbdxjXv10Pxnxtw.png

However once it gets near the bottom of the page I want it to be moved up a bit to fit a copyright sign under it.

Something along the lines of: margin-bottom: 0px until the bottom then 40px (or just not blocking the last 40px of space at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is something with what you can start ... To complete...

```js
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        document.getElementById('separator').className = "expand";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('separator').className = "";
    }
};
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#content{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(89, 255, 0, 0.258);
    height:  110vh;
}
footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.258);
}
#separator{
    width: 0px;
}
.expand {
    height: 100px;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <p>something</p>
    <div>
        <p>another</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>
<footer>
    your footer text
</footer>
```